How to read relative Distinguished Names if OID friendly names can't be parsed
I have to work with digital signatures, and part of it is reading relative distingushed names.
The problem is that Subject Name contains names that are not common, because they are related to country specific identifiers.
For example, Subject Name can look like this (omitting sensitive data):
CN=<...>, SN=<...>, G=<...>, T=<...>, STREET=<...>, O=<...>, L=<...>, S=<...>, C=RU, E=<...>, ИНН=<...>, ОГРН=<...>, СНИЛС=<...>, ИНН ЮЛ=<...>

It's not much of a problem if SubjectName is an X500DistinguishedName that was read from CAdES container using SignedCms class - I can define OID constants and compare OID values.
But it is a problem if SubjectName is provided separately from a certificate, as a string with friendly names, and is parsed using X500DistinguishedName(string) ctor, because

the names in question can be written in russian
On Windows locally they can be parsed, but they can't be on production environment, in Linux containers, and the code throws an exception:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: No OID value matches this name.


the names can also be written in english and this also needs to be parsed
ИНН could be INN, ИНН ЮЛ - INNLE, ОГРН - OGRN, СНИЛС - SNILS, etc
CN=<...>, SN=<...>, G=<...>, T=<...>, STREET=<...>, O=<...>, L=<...>, S=<...>, C=RU, E=<...>, INN=<...>, OGRN=<...>, SNILS=<...>, INNLE=<...>

these aren't parsed on a local machile because of different locale

OID friendly names are not guaranteed to be parsed at all
on some environments, some OIDs don't have a friendly name at all, so neither OGRN nor ОГРН have an OID match and throw an exception


So, the question is:
Is there an api that allows to read X.500 Distinguished Names without automatically doing OID lookup, in an anti-strict way?
So that data can still be parsed with knowledge on how this format works (semicolons, quotes, new lines, etc), but without restrictions regarding the aspect with no guarantees.
Or maybe some other way around, like adding sources for OID lookups in several locales.
I can parse the string manually, of course, but that feels like reinventing the wheel with possibility of parsing errors. I also tried replacing friendly names in a raw string with OID.<identifier>, before passing it to X500DistinguishedName constructor, but that also feels like something can go wrong (like replacing something in the RDN value)
Example CAdES container in PEM format: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Subject as a RU string:
CN="ООО ""Тестовая компания""", SN=Тестов, G=Аврелий Константинович, T=Тестовый руководитель, STREET="Наб. Тестовская, д. 29", O="ООО ""Тестовая компания""", L=Санкт-Тест, S=77 г. Москва, C=RU, E=test@example.com, ИНН=895017484750, ОГРН=5045222653086, СНИЛС=69463874569, ИНН ЮЛ=0906209499

Subject as a EN string:
CN="ООО ""Тестовая компания""", SN=Тестов, G=Аврелий Константинович, T=Тестовый руководитель, STREET="Наб. Тестовская, д. 29", O="ООО ""Тестовая компания""", L=Санкт-Тест, S=77 г. Москва, C=RU, E=test@example.com, INN=895017484750, OGRN=5045222653086, SNILS=69463874569, INNLE=0906209499


Hi Dmitry and welcome to Stackoverflow! Wouldn't the issue be to support international characters in distinguished names or add to your container whatever allows the signature verification to work on bare metal Windows ?

That could be a solution, unfortunately that link doesn't work for me. Will it work if there are distinguished names in several locales? (yeah, that's strange, but sadly it is what is)

Can you add a PEM encoded certificate example to your question (as text, so we can copy-paste it). That unreachable link mentions using certutil -asn {filename} to show data and its encoding. I would help understand if the bytes and encoding are coherent.

Oh, now I could open the link, no, the problem is not related to relative distinguished names values or its encoding. I can read certificate data, as I mentioned in the question, using OIDs. The problem is that I can't figure out how to parse distinguished name from a string, because, for example Oid.FromFriendlyName("ИНН") does not work in container. I'll clarify the question.

@ixe013, I've added signature cms pem with subject names as strings, if you're interested
